How to make TUN device accept incoming packets?
I'm working on the simple VPN server project for iOS.
iOS sends intercepted packets to Go server with UDP connection, then those packets are injected into the TUN device.
Go server workflow:

Create TUN device
Create UDP listener
Start listening for packets from TUN device
Start listening for packets from UDP connection

TUN device initialisation:
func CreateTun() (*water.Interface, error) {
        tun_ip := "192.168.9.11"
    config := water.Config{
        DeviceType: water.TUN,
    }

    iface, err := water.New(config)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    _, err := util.RunCommand(fmt.Sprintf("sudo ip addr add %s/24 dev %s", tun_ip, iface.Name()))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    _, err = util.RunCommand(fmt.Sprintf("sudo ip link set dev %s up", iface.Name()))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return iface, nil
}

UDP listener initialisation:
func CreateUdpListener() (*net.UDPConn, error) {
    addr, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp", "<PUBLIC_IP>:8933")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return nil, err
    }
    return net.ListenUDP("udp", addr)
}

TUN device listener:
func ListenIface(iface *water.Interface, listener *net.UDPConn) {
    packet := make([]byte, 65535)

    for {
        _, err := iface.Read(packet)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            continue
        }

        log.Println("packet from iface")
    }
}

UDP listener:
func ListenUdpConnection(iface *water.Interface, listener *net.UDPConn) {
    for {
        packet := make([]byte, 65535)

        n, _, err := listener.ReadFromUDP(packet)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            continue
        }

        log.Println("packet from client")

        _, err := iface.Write(packet[:n])
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }
    }
}

Entry point(main func):
iface, err := CreateTun()
if err != nil {
    os.Exit(1)
}

listener, err := CreateUdpListener()
if err != nil {
    os.Exit(1)
}

go ListenIface(iface, listener)
go ListenUdpConnection(iface, listener)

So I can receive packets from iOS, then I also able to inject them to the TUN device. And that's all. TUN device doesn't receive TX packets. Thousands of RX packets, and 7 TX packets...

If I monitor tun0 with Wireshark, I can see that there are packets to send and no incoming packets from outside.
You may have noticed from the code that the TUN's ip is 192.168.9.11, but the Source IP(the IP where response packets should come) is 10.8.0.2, which is completely different. VPN in iOS is implemented so that it creates a TUN device, redirects all packets from all applications to it, and gives developers access to read and write packets to that TUN. So 10.8.0.2 is an IP of the iOS TUN device.
First of all I thought that the problem was exactly this and in the Source IP should be 192.168.9.11 - IP of the TUN device on the server. What I did - I set for the TUN device on iOS the same IP as TUN device on server has, so that in the Source IP there was the IP I needed. I know this is a very bad solution, but I do not yet know how to rewrite packet's Source IP in Go (if you have useful links on this issue - I will be glad). Anyway there must be 192.168.9.11 in the Source IP, but this is not enough.


Here's the desired communication flow diagram. The blue flow works well. But there's no incoming packets to server's TUN.

Finally, the question - what am I missing for my tan device to start receiving responses.
I am running a server on Ubuntu 20.04 with a public IP4 address.
I will be glad to receive any answers.

Can you provide a diagram of your desired communication flow?

@vidarlo yes, sure. Just added a diagram.

Nothing comes back because there's no route for stuff to go back. There's two ways to fix that:

NAT where your server that hosts the VPN end point masquerades outgoing traffic.
Using routable IP's (non-RFC1918) to achieve End to End connectivity, and enable IP forwarding.

3.133.41.129 doesn't have the faintest idea how to reach 192.168.9.11, or even which 192.168.9.11 in the world it should reach. The NAT approach with masquerading will make all packets travelling to the internet appear to be from your server.

Thank you for the answer. How can I implement the first approach? What instruments and parameters should I use?

Depends on your operating system. Google  masquerade, and you'll probably get solid tutorials. On Linux you typically use iptables/nf for this.

Did I get it right that NAT will rewrite Source IP of the packets? Instead of 192.168.9.11 there will be Public IP address of machine in the Source IP field?

Yes, you want masquerade or source nat, which rewrites the source.

Okay, machine has received the response packets, because there is it's IP address in the Source IP field of the outgoing packets. But how it will realize that that response packets should be routed to my TUN? We have replaced 192.168.9.11 with Public IP address. Please, let me know if I'm asking dumb questions, I'm not as deep into the Networking as I want :)

Well, then it should maintain a state, and forward said packets to your tunnel device. But I would really suggest hiring someone with a basic understanding of IPv4 at this point.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Stack asked me to continue in the chat

I feel like you're trying to do too much at once. Straightforward use of TUN doesn't require any rewriting of any address. Sure, most VPN apps do such rewriting, but that's something you'd do after getting the TUN interface work on its own. (And the rewriting would be done by the OS as part of IP routing; not by your app at all.)

You need rewriting when a rfc1918 network wants to talk to hosts on the internet.

@u1686_grawity What do you mean on its own? TUN is working. I can write packets there. I can see them in the Wireshark.
